# Angular js error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

On including the jquery file prior to angular js file ,angular js is giving the following error,actually I was working with the reverse order, to create a date-picker directive I have to use the js files in following order,

jquery->jquery-ui->angular js;

when I use

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
```

I get the following error in console.

```
`"Error: f.on is not a function
wd/this.$get<@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:85
d@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:32
$b/q.$injector<@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:34
c@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:32
d@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:32
$b/q.$injector<@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:34
c@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:32
d@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:32
k/</<@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:42
r@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:9
k/<@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:42
d@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:32
$b/q.$injector<@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:34
c@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:32
v@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:55
U@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:46
M@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:45
M@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:45
Y@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:44
Zb/c/</<@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:20
Ed/this.$get</h.prototype.$eval@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:107
Ed/this.$get</h.prototype.$apply@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:108
Zb/c/<@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:20
d@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:32
Zb/c@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:20
Zb@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:20
Uc@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:19
@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/angular.js:208
.ready@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js:26
L@file:///C:/Users/Samsung/Google%20Drive/www/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js:33
"`
```

when I use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

there is no problem and things work fine.
using angular js 1.2.14
please help me.

Comment: use an unminified version and paste a useful error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I used jquery version 1.4 which was not going good with the angular js version 1.2.14
so after realizing that I changd the version and now its working good